# c# extremely easy unit test error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-console

I write this helloworld unit test and build it. It always have this build error: "`The command://...../Nunit.ConsoleRunner3.6/nunit3-console.exe exited with code 1`".I search all the stackoverflow but there is no a single thread about Nunit test exist code 1, do you know where can I find the information for this code?

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SomeName
{
    [TestFixture]
    class IdentifierTest
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {

        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {

        }

        [Test]
        public void DetectIDTest()
        {     
            Assert.AreEqual("hi","ho");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A positive exit code indicates the number of tests that has failed (in your case 1) as per [this](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/ConsoleRunner.cs#L256) line in the NUnit console runner source code. Additional (negative) failure codes also have meaning per [these](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/ConsoleRunner.cs#L45) six lines. This is substantiated by a discussion about exit codes [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/1BXhewdOgho), I have attached the response as an image for easy reference
[image]

Comment: I should have 10 failed test in the entire solution, why it only shows only the current working one failed test? @DeadlyEmbrace

Comment: I think it shows only failures from the executed test set. So if you run all test in your solution it should return 10. Overall, I wouldn't worry too much about positive return code values, they simply indicate that one or more tests have failed. The negative codes are the real "problem children"